# Intellij + FunSuite weird Behavior

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Intellij running tests on scala. I guess It is a configuration issue but I can't figure it out.

1.- When I write some simple test like below, I got the message: "class MyTest must either be declare as abstract or implement abstract member 'expectedTestCount' ... "

```
    class MyTest extends FunSuite {
       test("a") {
         assert(true)
       }
    }
```

But I am just following scala's documentation in which no overriding is going on. It compiles and I can run the test, but it is anoying

2.- The other weird thing is the triple equal operator (===). You can use it in scala for a better explanation on tests, but Intellij seems to not recognize It: "cannot resolve symbol ===" message pops up when writing it. Again It compiles and works OK but you get all your code in alarm red

Any suggestion?

Best regards

Comment: try rebuilding your project.

Comment: I tried already...